# Make a mobile number send an SMS

Tags: c#, api, sms, message, send

i am thinking if it is possible to have a (remote) cell/mobile number send an SMS via C#?

for example, my cell number is +00 000 000 0000 and i want it to send a message to 0000 and say "Hello There", is there such technology that can do as such? This is different from using an SMS Gateway API which uses a specific number and send to 0000. I want my own cell number to send that message without touching my phone, is it possible via any AT Commands, or are there any (free) API that can help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: By using AT commands you can send and read SMS and make calls (from PC using serial ports) reference :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com

Comment: @Znaneswar it wont work if the sim card is installed on a remote device? i.e.: a pocket wifi device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get your PC to make your phone send an SMS message, you would have to build two pieces of software:

1. You would have to write a mobile app native to the phone's operating system that listens to some kind of push notification service to know to when to send a message.  Depending on the phone OS, it may or may not be possible to actually send an SMS without first rooting the phone.
2. You would then need to write code on your PC to send a push notification that your phone app would receive, respond to, and send the SMS message.

If you are asking can you write mobile app software that can cause the phone it is running on to send an SMS, well I would refer you to the SDK of the phone OS you are targeting for that information.

Comment: yes, i already considered that. but i was thinking of having the sim card inside a pocket wifi

Answer (score 0):

Try Twilio: https://www.twilio.com/.

I'm using it for most of my projects.
You can try for free for 30 days. After the trial is over, you have to upgrade your account with at least 20.00 US$.

It supports plenty of programming languages, including .Net, Java, Python, etc.

Comment: i have already conducted a research about this and lots of api. however, what i want is for the sim card itself to send the message.